# C++ or Java for a career in Information Security

Tags: career

I wanted to know which language should i chose if i want to have a career in information security later on (about to get into college). I have even read that c dominates c++ and if that is the case is it tough switching between the syntax of the two?. I would also appreciate if you could mention some sites where i can learn some basics on hacking,exploits,encryption,and more.

Comment: Please this is not a duplicate! What about the other questions? At least read the entire question before marking as a duplicate this is a very important question to me. If you do know the answer then please share.

Comment: The answer given there IS relevant. It clearly says, "the programming language doesn't matter".

Comment: Just start learning.  Whether you learn Java or C++ or python or ruby or C or lua or javascript or bash scripting or haskell or assembly ... *first* doesn't matter the least and is a subjective opinion; ultimately they can all do the same things and you end up learning.  Yeah, there are minor syntactic differences, as well as meaningful differences between languages for how convenient or fast it is to do certain things.  First learn to program.  Then, take a course in cryptography and networking.  Read a book on hacking (e.g., hacking art of exploitation, or Web Application Hacker's Handbook).

Answer (score 4):

Don't choose; learn both.

If you want to make a career which involves programming (and most careers in information security do that), then you must learn *programming*, not *programming languages*. If you concentrate on a single language then you will be a very poor programmer, and your career will fail.

Programming is a state of the mind; languages are distractions.

Answer (score 3):

Information security is a broad field. Depending on the branch you want to specialize you might find useful to learn C, C++, Java, python, shellscripting or neither. About the two you have mention:

1. C++ will give you a lot of knowledge about how memory should be managed, and how to build secure code with these assumptions.
2. Java will give you a lot of knowledge about how a virtual machine works and how to build secure code with these assumptions.
3. Others will tell you that once you know how to program, selecting a language program is about knowing some small details.

Consider that even after mastering the two of them you will learn nothing about communications, cryptography, secret management...  Securing is not about programming languages. Securing (well, a big simplification) is about information and how is it treated, stored, shared and by whom (confidentiality, availability, integrity and non-repudio).

But if you want a closer tech security approach...

I learnt a lot about security getting into the Debian (linux) world, I really believe that getting inside the linux administration world will give you big notions about security and security design. Then learning basic cryptography and how communications works will give you the rest. After you have managed all these concepts (and believe me, that is a lot to say) you will need to take into consideration thousands of regulations and security standards.

Is an arduous path, but it is a nice one =)

[Edit] Addendum: 
I belive the better place to learn about the topics you want is a forum, any hacking forum will do for a beginner level... You eventually will meet people and will find sources of information as you continue learning.

Comment: Thanks for the well thought answer kiBytes i think that was the answer i required and i will definitely explore linux. You also mentioned learning from forums; it would be great if you could mention some as most i find are blogs by 5 year olds with not much information

Comment: I really can't suggest you any forum (maybe BB forum via Tor) because I haven't used them since old times. Please, also consider marking the question as the correct if you feel like :)

Comment: Java can be helpful in Android pentesting too